# How to remove small gaps on firefox window titlebar in gnome?

Tags: gnome

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 with the gnome desktop environment. The display on my machine is high pixel density, so I have the HiDPI window scaling enabled. I followed [this](https://ryanclouser.com/2015/07/16/GNOME-3-14-HiDPI-Scaling-4K/) tutorial to get everything looking good, and it seems to have done the trick. also I have layout.css.PixelsPerPx set to 1.5 to scale firefox to the HiDPI display.

There is one more thing I'd like to fix. When maximized, the firefox window titlebar has small gaps on either side, as can be seen in this picture:

[image]

Does anybody know how this can be fixed? I'd ideally like the titlebar to span that region with gaps.

It seems that other programs like the system file browser do not have these gaps.

Comment: That screenshot seems to be rather squished.

Comment: Are you not able to see the gaps on the top and bottom of the titlebar? Sorry, I figured that zooming in may help.